# NSURL with a custom scheme?

Tags: cocoa, nsurl

I'm making a document-based application, backed by an abstract file storage system.  Sometimes the files come from the local system (`file://`), sometimes they come from FTP, sometimes they come from SFTP, or theoretically even some non-standard scheme.

For all the local files I've been initializing `NSData` from the URL of the file.  Ideally I'd like this to work for URLs like `sftp://server.tld:22/...` too, but I'm unsure if NSURL provides support for providing custom I/O operations for shemes it doesn't handle out of the box.

Does anyone know if you can register I/O handlers for non-standard URL schemes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you subclass `NSURLProtocol`.